# How to package a Node 10 application as a signable executable for macOS?

Tags: node.js, macos, xcode6, executable, code-signing

I've been scouring the web and come across a few options for packaging, such as [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) and [node-packer](https://github.com/pmq20/node-packer), but all of these options have a fatal sticking point.

- **pkg:** Works great, but cannot sign the executables for macOS  (something about extra Python data appended to the executable)
- **node-packer:** Doesn't support Node 10. Found a fork that does and spent hours tinkering, but never got a built executable, let alone getting to the signing point

Is there any option for building a plain node executable for macOS with code signing? I can't use Electron for this case unfortunately.